# How do I extending native class by webpack in javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Say if I want to add a `groupBy` method to the `Array` class by the following code in the `src/extend.js` file,

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function (prop) {
  return this.reduce((groups, item) => {
    const val = item[prop];
    groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
    groups[val].push(item);
    return groups;
  }, {});
};
```

I want this file to be only `require` only once globally then the `groupBy` method can be used in every file in my project, no need to be `require` in every file.

How do I achieve that in webpack?

Comment: require in your entrypoint.

Comment: @MatheusSilva Good idea! Thanks!